# Why does my Python script result in "permission denied" when I run it from the terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

I'm just starting learning terminal usage. My Python code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

name = input("What's your name? ")

print(f"Hello, {name}!")
```

What I type on terminal:

```
chmod +x firstscript.py
```

then

```
./firstscript.py
```

The output:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: Permission denied
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the result of `which python3`? Run `ls -l LOCATION` on the returned location of the first command. Does it have any `x` flags enabled?

Comment: `which  returns  the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed` and it wouldn't return anything if the python3 is indeed not executable.  It's kinda weird that env doesn't give more useful information like what path it tried to execute last.

Answer (score 0):

The python3 file that env finds is not executable.  `strace -f ./firstscript.py |& grep execve` will guide your quest to find what path it used.  If those permissions look good, use `mount -l` to see of the file system was mounted with noexec.